# Select the array where championship_id = 13

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array with 2 championships.

Each championship have his own array of teams and competitors

How should I select the array element which has the championship_id I need.

What I meen is I will need to access `{{team.name}}` and in PHP, I have the championshipId value, I mean anywhere in code, I could include `:championship-id= 13`.

What I don't know how to do is select the array that have championship_id = 13

Or should I change my array structure so it is easier to get the teams and competitors I need?

Here is the structure of my array

```
   array:2 [▼
0 => array:3 [▼
  "championship" => 13
  "competitors" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 104
      "name" => "email@email.com"
    ]
  ]
  "teams" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "t1"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "name" => "t2"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "t3"
    ]
  ]
]
1 => array:3 [▼
  "championship" => 15
  "competitors" => array:5 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 104
      "name" => "email@email.com"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 105
      "name" => "julien2"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 106
      "name" => "email@email.com2"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 107
      "name" => "email@email.com2"
    ]
    4 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 108
      "name" => "eee@email.comw"
    ]
  ]
  "teams" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 4
      "name" => "rr1"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 5
      "name" => "rr2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is probably what you're looking for.

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

So:

```
const arr = ...
const targetID = 13;
const championship = arr.find((elem) => elem.championship_id == targetID);
```

Comment: if I use it in the same script, it works, tx. But I don't know how to use it with vueJs 2. I have : <div v-for="team in teams"> where teams should be arr.find((elem) => elem.championship_id == targetID).teams, but it doesn't work